# MySQL difference between @@global.timezone and @@system_time_zone

Tags: mysql

I can take some guesses but I can't find a specific answer to what the difference is between @@global.timezone and @@system_time_zone.  I assume @@global is a set of variables set for MySQL and that they can be set in My.cnf ?  And that as I haven't set it that is why if I run

```
SELECT @@global.timezone;
```

I get a response of SYSTEM.

On my linux dev machine I have a system date setting of BST and so, I assume, that is why when I run

```
SELECT @@system_time_zone;
```

I get a response of BST.

Is this correct ?  If it is correct does this mean I can change the @@global.timezone by setting values in my.cnf but that the only way I can change the @@system_time_zone setting is by changing the linux server date configuration ?  Or is there a way I can update the @@system_time_zone in MySQL ?

To be honest the main thrust of this question is to fully understand the difference between global and system time zone but knowing how to change the system_time_zone would be a great (I'm using quite an old version - 5.6.46 and 5.6.47 (2 different machines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty well documented in the MySQL Reference Manual.  Not really a need to "guess" or "assume" when we can look it up.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html

excerpts:

> The system time zone. When the server starts, it attempts to determine the time zone of the host machine automatically and uses it to set the **`system_time_zone`** system variable. The value does not change thereafter.
>
> To explicitly specify the system time zone for MySQL Server at startup, set the `TZ` environment variable before you start `mysqld`. If you start the server using `mysqld_safe`, its `--timezone` option provides another way to set the system time zone. The permissible values for `TZ` and `--timezone` are system dependent. Consult your operating system documentation to see what values are acceptable.

---

> The server current time zone. The global **`time_zone`** system variable indicates the time zone the server currently is operating in. The initial time_zone value is 'SYSTEM', which indicates that the server time zone is the same as the system time zone.

---

(My apologies if you've already reviewed the documentation, and didn't have any specific question that wasn't answered there... there's no mention in the question that the documentation had already been consulted.)

Comment: yes apologies I got blind sided by external docs not quite giving me the answer I wanted and missed the actual reference manual.  I've not been able to set the System time zone in the my.cnf, but have had no problem setting global (default-time-zone).  Will give that up now but if you can set it in my.cnf please let me know.

Comment: @gringogordo: not possible to set system_time_zone in the my.cnf, MySQL is getting that "from the system"... according to the docs, it looks like it's checking the `TZ` environment variable on the OS.  My opinion, is to not be concerned with system_time_zone, and make sure MySQL `time_zone` is not set to SYSTEM...  if my MySQL database instance has to be restored to a different machine, I want my database to be independent of the OS timezone.